# Parse special character with jquery json

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "parse": {
        "title":"Wiki",
        "revid":491629701,
        "text": {
            "*": "<div class=\"dablink\">"
        }
    }
}
```

And I try to access: `parse->text->*`:

```
$.getJSON(
    'my_url&callback=?', 
    function(json) {    
        console.log(json.parse.text.*); 
    }
);
```

The following error appears:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * .

How can I properly parse this object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) instead:

```
console.log(json.parse.text["*"]);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nnefq/